# Salesforce API - have auth token; can't make API call

Tags: api, oauth

I'm having the same issue as this user in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51633/session-expired-or-invalid-have-auth-token-cant-make-api-call), but the answer provided doesn't work in my.

I can connect, I can retrieve a auth token, but when I immediately make a call with it it fails with:

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Not sure if this is relevant: it was working fine but then I refreshed our sandbox with what is in production, and so had to make a new Connected App from scratch, and now it no longer works. I'm not sure if I could have lost some basic settings (organization wide settings?) that are outside of the app? I did of course update the client_id and client_secret to the new App and set permissions to use the api and all that.

I am using [this library](https://github.com/jahumes/salesforce-rest-api-php-wrapper) which is great and I was using it previously so I'm positive it isn't that but provide it just to provide it.

Comment: I'm sure you checked this, but I was having a similar issue, and it had to do with the encoding.  I ended up testing it in the Chrome Advanced Rest Client and it eventually worked, but I needed to fix my original code.

Comment: interesting, I'll check into that. What did you change? You mean your headers to utf-8 or something?

Comment: Silly question, but you *are* making sure you use the server URL you get in the auth response, right? You'll get an invalid session ID error if you hit the wrong endpoint. This has confused me on at least one occasion. Make sure you didn't hardcode your endpoint URL or something silly like that.

Comment: @dgig I mean in my post to get Authentication, the header "Content-Type" is x-www-form-urlencoded.  I take the response and fill in the Secret and Token but this post is encoded as "applications/json"

Comment: For all of the APIs, the endpoint *can* and probably *will* change at some point. You must always use instance_url (REST) or serverURL (SOAP) after a login. In the case of a sandbox refresh, if your pod changes (e.g. from cs10 to cs20), your endpoint will *also* change, guaranteed. In other cases, salesforce has made changes to how endpoints work (e.g. na1-api was an old naming style, but they now use just na1 for that pod). It is never safe to assume that any endpoint other than the login URL will never change.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. What's strange now is that, though this works for retrieving basic info (api versions) it gives 404 errors on everything specific to my Account (/sobjects/Account/describe/ for instance).

Comment: Gah, I just looked through the code, it IS actually fixing the instance_url each time (I'm using user/password auth). So, it isn't that. And my forcing the change is just pointing me at the wrong instance now hence the 404s.